# Multi views with children

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a layout with header, footer, sidebar and content that should be used for some pages. All pages should be includes inside the content section.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="main-header" ui-view="header"></header>
    <aside class="main-sidebar" ui-view="left"></aside>
    <div class="content-wrapper" ui-view></div><!-- all pages should be included here -->
    <footer class="main-footer" ui-view="footer"></footer>
    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark" ui-view="right"></aside>
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
```

My routes:

```
.state('main', {
    views: {
        'left': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/design/left.html'
        },
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/design/header.html'
        },
        'right': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/design/right.html'
        },
        'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/design/footer.html'
        }
    },
    url: '/'
})
.state('info', {
    url: '/info',
    templateUrl: "partials/info.html",
})
.state('foobar', {
    url: '/foobar',
    templateUrl: "partials/foobar.html",
})
```

So info and foobar should be childrens of main, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.state('info', {
    url: '/info',
    templateUrl: "partials/info.html",
})
.state('foobar', {
    url: '/foobar',
    templateUrl: "partials/foobar.html",
})
```

Do this:

```
.state('main.info', {
    url: '/info',
    templateUrl: "partials/info.html",
})
.state('main.foobar', {
    url: '/foobar',
    templateUrl: "partials/foobar.html",
})
```

Comment: when I do this he loads all html files and includes everything in the right place, except the info.html and foobar.html into the empty ui-view

Comment: Does it show foobar.html or info.html in the main page if the URL is /foobar or /info?

Comment: It loads the the foobar.html, but it is not included into the ui-view

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is also possible with `ng-include`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="main-header" ng-include src="'partials/design/header.html'"></header>
    <aside class="main-sidebar" ng-include src="'partials/design/left.html'"></aside>
    <div class="content-wrapper"><ui-view></ui-view></div><!-- all pages should be included here -->
    <footer class="main-footer"ng-include src="'partials/design/footer.html'"></footer>
    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark" ng-include src="'partials/design/right.html'"></aside>
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
```

So everyone who has this template as parent will be shown in the `<ui-view></ui-view>`section.